# Does "leading" here mean that Neville is coming with Professor McGonagall?

Tags: harry-potter, language-explanation

Neville and Professor McGonagall appear to be together here, or am I mistaken?

> Had Harry thought that things couldn’t have been worse? He was wrong. When Professor McGonagall appeared, she was leading Neville.
>
> ‘Harry!’ Neville burst out, the moment he saw the other two. ‘I was trying to find you to warn you, I heard Malfoy saying he was going to catch you, he said you had a drag–’
>
> Harry shook his head violently to shut Neville up, but Professor McGonagall had seen. She looked more likely to breathe fire than Norbert as she towered over the three of them.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone - Chapter Fifteen: The Forbidden Forest</sup></sub>

"Leading" here implies that he is coming with her, but the fact that he talked to Harry about the dragon makes me suspicious. Was he somehow unaware of her presence?

Comment: "Burst" implies that Neville was excited and not truly controlling himself

Comment: Neville is a 11 year old with poor impulse control, as every child of that age.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes

Neville and McGonagil are travelling together with Neville slightly behind.

Neville was not unaware of her presence, he was just a little … focused on telling Harry what he knew, would be the polite way to put it. Dumb would be harsh but fair.